# pjax vs wiselinks, differences

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser-history, pjax

What is the difference, and which one is faster?

**+1 for wiselinks**, it can be used like this:

```
<a href="/?page=2" data-push="true" data-target="@catalog">2</a>
```

so it can target

```
<div role="catalog"></div>
```

and replace its content.

**+1 for pjax**, it can redirect when php server-side do redirect.

Correct me if i'm wrong.

Your opinions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wiselinks can process forms for example, and it can work in non-HTML5 browsers.
And by the way, don't forget to add role.js to use @role selectors in JQuery.

Comment: what about this thing with redirect ?

Comment: I will try to implement this in latest release.

Comment: Thanks, when next release will be out ?

Comment: Currently working on it, so wait for it till the end of weekend or maybe at the beginning of next week.

Comment: Added support of HTTP 30x redirect in wiselinks-0.5.x